# Conditional render 1 of 3 components on button click (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-frontend

I'm new to react and been struggling to figure out how to render the components inside the container depending on which button has been clicked.

I've set the state to false, then on the button click set it to true then used a ternary operator to show or set the component to null but won't work when the next button is clicked because the state is already set to true.

any help in the right direction would be appreciated :)

```
const AboutUs = () => {

  const [VisDetails, setVisDetails] = useState(false);

  return (

<Button>Personal Details</Button>
<Button>Bio</Button>
<Button>Qualifications</Button>

Container className={classes.container}>

<PersonalDetails />
<ProfileBio />
<ProfileQualifications />

</Container>

  );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best thing to do in this case is save the state depending on what content should be showing and then update that state on button click.

Something like this

```
const AboutUs = () => {

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(//Here goes the default value you 
                                           //want to show, or null if you want no render);

  return (
    <Button onClick={() => { setSelected('personaldetails') }}>Personal Details</Button>
    <Button onClick={() => { setSelected('bio') }}>Bio</Button>
    <Button onClick={() => { setSelected('qualif') }}>Qualifications</Button>

    Container className={classes.container}>

    {
      (selected == 'personaldetails') ? <PersonalDetails /> : null
    }
    {
      (selected == 'bio') ? <ProfileBio /> : null
    }
    {
      (selected == 'qualif') ? <ProfileQualifications /> : null
    }

    </Container>
  );
};
```

You could use a switch() but I like the inline if statement, easier to read.

Comment: onClick expects a function

Comment: Oh, you're right, so you have to define a handler for each onClick, sometimes React is a bit messy. Ill change the answer.

Comment: Thank you this worked great. are there any advantages or disadvantages to using either ?

Comment: There is no significative advantage between switch and inline evaluation, i like the inline because is easier to read.
I will modify the answer there is a cleaner way without the handlers.
Please, tick the answer if it answered your question correctly :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the button click `selected` state receive the value which will be used in `showSelectedOption()` to return the right component.

```
const AboutUs = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState('');

const showSelectedOption = () => {
  switch(selected) {
    case 'details':
      return  <PersonalDetails />;
    case 'bio':
      return  <ProfileBio />;
    case 'qualif':
      return  <ProfileQualifications />;
    default:
      return '';

  }
}

return (
   <Button onClick={() => setSelected('details')}>Personal Details</Button>
   <Button onClick={() => setSelected('bio')}>Bio</Button>
   <Button onClick={() => setSelected('qualif')}>Qualifications</Button>

   Container className={classes.container}>
      {showSelectedOption()} 
   </Container>
  );
};
```